# Discord.js Issue with async and await

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was changing my code to include async and await

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'claim',
    description: 'claiming an order',
    args: 'true',
    usage: '<order id>',
    aliases: ['ao'],
    examples: 'claim a12',
    employeeOnly: 'true',
    async execute(message, prefix) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

        let ticketID = args[1];
                
        await fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then((orderDB) => {
                    
            const order = orderDB[ticketID];
            
            let orderclaimed = await db.get(`User${message.author.id}.orderclaimed`)
            
            if(orderclaimed !== null) return message.reply(`You already have claimed an order before! deliver it first! ID: ${orderclaimed}`)
          
            if(order === undefined) {
              message.reply(`Couldn't find order \`${args[1]}\` Try again.`);

            return;
            }
 // rest of code
```

but at the line

```
let orderclaimed = await db.get(`User${message.author.id}.orderclaimed`)
```

I get this error

```
await db.set(`User${message.author.id}.orderclaimed`, ticketID)
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

but I included async in the execute function, where do I need to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You entered a new scope when using the `.then(...)` callback, you must now make that function `async`

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'claim',
    description: 'claiming an order',
    args: 'true',
    usage: '<order id>',
    aliases: ['ao'],
    examples: 'claim a12',
    employeeOnly: 'true',
    async execute(message, prefix) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);

        let ticketID = args[1];
                
        // Make this async aswell
        await fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then(async orderDB => {
                    
            const order = orderDB[ticketID];
            
            let orderclaimed = await db.get(`User${message.author.id}.orderclaimed`)
            
            if(orderclaimed !== null) return message.reply(`You already have claimed an order before! deliver it first! ID: ${orderclaimed}`)
          
            if(order === undefined) {
              message.reply(`Couldn't find order \`${args[1]}\` Try again.`);

            return;
            }
```

You can also just `await` the result of `readJSON(...)` for the code to all fall under the same scope.

```
const orderDB = await fsn.readJSON("./orders.json")
// Rest of your code
```

Comment: Might seem worth recommending removing the then altogether and using await throughout.